# Determine path of native library (dll / so)

Tags: java, dll, shared-libraries

The `System.loadLibrary("Something")` will load `libSomething.so` or `Something.dll` depending on platform. It will search for it in a list of directories (`java.library.path`) and will load the first it finds (I think).

I would like to know the full path of the loaded `.so` / `.dll`. There is `ClassLoader.findLibrary(String libname)` which does exactly what I want, but it is `protected`.

A workaround option could be to use `System.mapLibraryName(String)` to make platform specific file name from the library name and then to split and iterate through the `java.library.path` system property. I suppose it would give the same result as `ClassLoader.finLibrary` for most cases, but would it for all cases?

Is there any best practice for this task?

Comment: If the `ClassLoader` method is good, inherit `ClassLoader` and add a public method that just calls the protected one.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551588/can-i-find-out-what-variable-java-library-path-maps-to-on-the-current-platform