# How can i know java library path?

Tags: java

I'm new to java i need to know where is  `java library path` to add it in my open source
 i searched for is this command

```
which java
```

gave me

```
/usr/bin/java
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I find out what variable java.library.path maps to on the current platform?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551588/can-i-find-out-what-variable-java-library-path-maps-to-on-the-current-platform)

Comment: The linked question's top answer has a sample `LibPathFinder` you can use.

Comment: is there anyother way to know the path instead of coding ? like command in terminal ?

Comment: @Begnnier, Why do you need to set a native library?

Comment: @Perdomoff i read that in the link you sent that i should follow steps one of them set the native libraries

Comment: Some Java frameworks depend on native code. Does your application depend on another language? Are you trying to add jars to your project?  Help me understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: i think you are right i didn't get it well , i need to know where can i find java library path i have in my pc to use it

Comment: Are you looking for the java home directory?" [How to find my current JAVA_HOME in ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/459900/how-to-find-my-current-java-home-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @Perdomoff sorry for my late reply , no i couldn't i searched manually and i got JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64 that i wrote it in bashrc but didn't help

Comment: Tell me what you're looking for and for what purpose? Let's fix this.

Comment: @Perdomoff could that path is the java.library.path /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/lib ? i used sudo update-alternatives --config java

Comment: Yes, build the application.

Comment: Really Thanks @Perdomoff for your time and help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
```

console:

```
java -XshowSettings:properties
```

Comment: is there anyother way to know the path instead of coding ? like command in terminal ?

Comment: i got Unrecognized option: -XshowSettings:properties
Could not create the Java virtual machine.

Comment: @Begnnier What operating system?

Comment: i checked it now again , there is no error in spaces

Comment: What do you get when you type in your console:

 echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: @Begnnier, Read this, you may have not set it yet:[java.library.path – What is it and how to use](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/java-library-path-what-is-it-and-how-to-use/)

Comment: i read it now and what i got that there is another way to set it by iDE and i'm using eclipse and set it already
so should i set it again or not ?

Comment: @Begnnier, follow the link and then let's try to get that path you set.

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow the symbolic links.

```
ls -lah /usr/bin/java
/usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java

ls -lah /etc/alternatives/java
/etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

Comment: sorry i'm new , this lines indicates to what ? i mean this are commands or the default paths of java library ?