# Maven, Tomcat, java.library.path and %PATH%: A strange love affair

Tags: java, windows, maven, tomcat, jco

I've been struggling for days to recognize what is going on with my current Java Maven project that uses Tomcat and external libraries (JCo).
For some reason, the `System.getProperty("java.library.path")` result does not match the paths from my enviroment variable `%PATH%` (default).
**I do NOT intend to change the `java.library.path` value or whatsoever**, I just want to know **why it is *NOT DEFAULTING* to the %PATH%** variable.

Here's how I identified it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (String path : System.getProperty("java.library.path")) {
        System.out.println(path);
    }
}
```

The above snippet results in:

`C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin
C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin
C:\WINDOWS\system32
C:\WINDOWS
C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_131/bin/server
C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_131/bin
C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_131/lib/amd64
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin
C:\Python27
C:\Python27\Scripts
C:Program Files\Git\bin
C:Program Files\Git\cmd
\C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\
C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\
C:\Windows\system32
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT
C:\Users\Unknown\.dnx\bin
C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Emulator Manager\1.0\
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\
C:\WINDOWS\system32
C:\WINDOWS
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin
D:\Arquivos de Programas\Apache Software Foundation\Maven 3.3.9\bin
C:\Pro
C:\Users\Unknown\AppData\Roaming\npm
C:\Users\Unknown\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
C:\Program Files\Eclipse Neon
.`

...while the `echo %PATH%` produces the following results:

`C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin
C:\Python27
C:\Python27\Scripts
C:\WEEEEEEEEEEEIRD\PAAAAAAAATHHHHHH\FOR MAVEN EXAMPLE
C:Program Files\Git\bin
C:Program Files\Git\cmd
\C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\
C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\
C:\Windows\system32
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT
C:\Users\Unknown\.dnx\bin
C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Emulator Manager\1.0\
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\
C:\WINDOWS\system32
C:\WINDOWS
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin
D:\Arquivos de Programas\Apache Software Foundation\Maven 3.3.9\bin
D:\Arquivos de Programas\SAP\JCo
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\
C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\
C:\Windows\system32
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT
C:\Users\Unknown\.dnx\bin
C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Emulator Manager\1.0\
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\
C:\Pro
C:\Users\Unknown\AppData\Roaming\npm
C:\Users\Unknown\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps`

As we can see, the "C:\WEEEEEEEEEEEIRD\PAAAAAAAATHHHHHH\FOR MAVEN EXAMPLE" from `%PATH%` does not show in the `java.library.path`. This path contains the required DLL for my project.

What could be wrong? Thanks a lot in advance!

I'm using:

- Windows 10 x64
- Maven 3.3.9
- Tomcat 9
- Java 8
- Eclipse Neon
- JCo 3 (SAP Java Connector)
- Hibersap 1.3.0 (JCo "wrapper")

Pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.com.nooder</groupId>
    <artifactId>Hibersap</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Hibersap</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibersap</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibersap-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibersap</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibersap-jco</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.hibersap -DartifactId=com.sap.conn.jco.sapjco3 -Dversion=3.0.16 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile="C:\somewhere\sapjco3.jar" -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibersap</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.sap.conn.jco.sapjco3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.16</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!--
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <propertyName>java.library.path</propertyName>
                        <buildDirectory>D:\Arquivos de Programas\SAP\JCo</buildDirectory>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            -->
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I find out what variable java.library.path maps to on the current platform?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551588/can-i-find-out-what-variable-java-library-path-maps-to-on-the-current-platform)

Comment: If you are doing this in any IDE, chances are that IDE is setting some environment variables upon startup.

Comment: @Berger your link helps just a single bit. One useful information I got from it is `java.library.path isn't guaranteed to be set from an environment variable at all`, although I want to know how is the `java.library.path` defaultly created

Comment: @YvesHenri : the point is that you can't rely on an environment variable to provide your expected library path , you should really customize the `-Djava.library.path` VM argument .

Comment: @Berger people say that `java.library.path` defaults to %PATH% on Windows enviroments. Is that false, then? This native lib my project requires is due to that JCo component (developed by SAP - sap.com). To keep my life easy, I dont want to relay on remembering to change anything, except adding the path to the lib to my %path% variable (if and only if `java.library.path` defaulted to %path%). Also, changing anything other than the previous example sounds like a trouble when working on this project with multiple developers. I'm sure there is a maven plugin or something that will solve it...